# VS Code not stopping at breakpoint with PHP XDebug

Tags: php, laravel, visual-studio-code, wamp, xdebug

i'm working in Laravel application, i'm trying to use XDEBUG with WAMP Server and Visual Studio code, when i run "Listen for XDEBUG" in VS code it dosen't stop at break point but the page still in charge it's like the debug is working but not stopping in breakpoint.

I already have added XDEBUG's extension in Chrome

Here's my Lanch.Json :

```
{
    // Use IntelliSense to learn about possible attributes.
    // Hover to view descriptions of existing attributes.
    // For more information, visit: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=830387
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Listen for XDebug",
            "type": "php",
            "request": "launch",
            "port": 8000
        },
        {
            "name": "Launch currently open script",
            "type": "php",
            "request": "launch",
            "program": "${file}",
            "cwd": "${fileDirname}",
            "port": 9000
        }
    ]
}
```

And in my php.ini i have this at the end :

```
[xdebug]
zend_extension="c:/wamp64/bin/php/php7.2.25/zend_ext/php_xdebug-2.8.0-7.2-vc15-x86_64.dll"
xdebug.remote_enable =1
xdebug.profiler_enable =1
xdebug.profiler_enable_trigger =1
xdebug.profiler_output_name = cachegrind.out.%t.%p
xdebug.profiler_output_dir ="c:/wamp64/tmp"
xdebug.show_local_vars=0
xdebug.default_enable=1
xdebug.remote_host=127.0.0.1
xdebug.remote_port=8000
```